# Attribute return null in xmlpullparser

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

I don't know why return null value in getAttributeValue(). I need to get some attributes from a XML file. Please help me.

```
case XmlPullParser.END_TAG: 
  if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_MARKER)) {
    stackSites.add(curStackSite);
  } else if (tagname.equals(KEY_TITULO)) {
    String title = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "provincia");
    if (title!=null){
      curStackSite.setTitulo(title);
    }else{
      curStackSite.setTitulo("Es null");
    }                       
    xpp.nextTag();      
  } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_LINK)) {
    curStackSite.setLink(curText);
  } 
break;
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stack-sites>
    <marker>
        <titulo provincia="Pich">Pichincha</titulo>
        <link>http://stackoverflow.com/</link>
        <fecha>2014/08/12 14:57:59</fecha>
        <image>https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5724095/XmlParseExample/stackoverflow.png</image>
        <lat>-0.1</lat>
        <lng>-78.46</lng>
        <mag>4.1</mag>
        <depth>5</depth>
    </marker>
</stack-sites>
```

Comment: can you post your xml file ?

Comment: @mmlooloo I put the xml file so that you can view.

Comment: I made a change in the XML file like this <titulo provincia="Pich" /> and it worked. What should I do to get many attributes?. Sample: <marker provincia="Pich" ciudad="Quito"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a change in the XML file like this `<titulo provincia="Pich" />` and it worked.